# Passing select result to like operator in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have results of name in a customer table

I want to find whether this name is present in log table column

My log table changedate column will record name and also id, I want to find only name

```
select top 100 *
from LogDataTable
where ChangeData like '%'+'select name from customer'+ '%'
```

But I'm not getting results with this query, any changes I have to do? Can it done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a join to compare data the way you are asking e.g.

```
select top 100 L.*
from dbo.LogDataTable L
inner join dbo.Customer C on L.ChangeData like '%' + C.[Name] + '%';
```

Its not going to perform very well though, as it has to do a table scan of `Customer` for every row in `LogDataTable`.

If you were able to ensure that the Customer Name was always the first part of the `ChangeData` you could use `like C.[Name] + '%'` and then benefit from indexes.

To solve your collation error, re-collate of one of the columns in your query. I recommend changing `C.[Name]` since that is already the subject of a table scan. But it depends whether you need an "Accent Sensitive" compare or not e.g.

```
select top 100 L.*
from dbo.LogDataTable L
inner join dbo.Customer C on L.ChangeData like '%' + C.[Name] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + '%';
```

Comment: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the like operation.
I'm facing this error

Comment: you would add the collation characteristics too to fix this. Eg"inner join dbo.Customer C on L.ChangeData COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS like '%' + C.[Name] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + '%';